# Extract employee record based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, ssms-2017

I have a database of employees with their employment history in organization.

Sample Data -

```
+----+----------+------------+
| ID |   Date   |   Event    |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | 20190807 | Hired      |
|  1 | 20191209 | Promoted   |
|  1 | 20200415 | Terminated |
|  2 | 20180901 | Hired      |
|  2 | 20191231 | Terminated |
|  3 | 20180505 | Hired      |
|  3 | 20190630 | Promoted   |
+----+----------+------------+
```

I want to extract the list of employees who were terminated after promotion. In above example, the query should return ID 1.

I am using SSMS 17 if that helps.

Comment: It's not the version of SSMS that matters but rather the version of SQL Server to which it connects, as it's the Server that executes the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using lag()

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4cf6850dccb105c7f20c90b2ed4043e)**

```
select distinct ID from
(
select *,lag(event) over(partition by id order by dateval) as prevval
from t
)A where prevval='Promoted'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want *immediately* after, then you would use `lag()`.  If you want *any time after*, then you can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(case when event = 'Promoted' then dateval end) < max(case when event = 'Terminated' then dateval end);
```

Using `lag()`, the code looks like:

```
select id
from (select t.*, lag(event) over (partition by id order by dateval) as prev_event
      from t
     ) t
where prev_event = 'Promoted' and event = 'Terminated';
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `exists` check could also solve this simple requirement.

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=90f9eb59e1cfa4ee8ea5934cbc451e8e)**

```
select * from table1 a
where event='Terminated'
and exists(select 1 from table1 b where a.ID = b.ID  and event='Promoted');
```

output:

```
ID  date1       event
1   20191209    Terminated
```

We can even compare event date in correlated sub-query as shown in DEMO link.